# Multi-Thread Producer/Consumer Synchronization Issues

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer

I am having issues with two threads that dont seem to synchronize properly. I basically have an boolean value names "occupied". It is set to false when no thread is started. but when one starts, the thread sets occupied is true I have a class that has the thread (run) and they call the functions below.

This is a mock bank example that takes in an amount (initial balance) and then performs withdrawals and deposits randomly. My professor mention something about signaling form the withdraw thread to the deposit thread? How does that work? The withdraw thread, it should run until the balance is two low and wait for a deposit thread. How should i do that?

```
   package bank;

import java.util.Random;
import bank.Bank;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;

/**
 *
 * @author KJ4CC
 */
public class Action {

    private Lock accessLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition cond = accessLock.newCondition();
    //private Condition withdraw  = accessLock.newCondition();


    Random rand = new Random();
    Object lock = new Object();
    Bank getBalance = new Bank();

    public void widthdrawl(int threadNum) throws InterruptedException {
        int amount = rand.nextInt(50);
            accessLock.lock();

            if (getBalance.getbalance() > amount) {

                getBalance.setBalance(getBalance.getbalance() - amount);

                System.out.println("\t\t\tThread " + threadNum + " withdrawls " + amount + "\t Balance is " + getBalance.getbalance());

            } else {

                System.out.println("\t\t\tThread " + threadNum + " Failed to withdrawl " + amount + "\t Balance is " + getBalance.getbalance());
                cond.await();

            }


            accessLock.unlock();
            Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(5));

    }

    public void deposit(int threadNum) throws InterruptedException {
        int amount = rand.nextInt(200);
        accessLock.lock();


            getBalance.setBalance(getBalance.getbalance() + amount);
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadNum + " Deposits " + amount + "\t\t\t\t Balance is " + getBalance.getbalance());
            Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(100));

            cond.signal();
            accessLock.unlock();


    }
}
```

Comment: Try checkout out a BlockingQueue.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Lock` and `Condition` usage is wrong. You're calling `lock()` without calling `unlock()` anywhere, and you're calling `signal()` without anyone having called `await()`.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) for an example **very much related** to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to mark you `occupid` variable [volatile](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html). Without this keyword changing the variable value in one thread won't be visible in another.

Second, you trying to implement external synchronization policy for `bank` entity. Such idea basically isn't good: if someone uses the same `bank` without properly synchronization it'll break internal bank state. It's better to implement internal synchronization policy and allow bank to guard its state by itself.

E.g. the API of `Bank` class may be like this

```
class Bank {
   double synchronize getBalance() { ... }
   void synchronize deposit(double amount) { ... }
   void synchronize widthdrawl(double amount) throw BankException { ... }
}
```

With this design internal `Bank` state always be consistent and *any* `Bank` users will be wait finishing current bank operation automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: He doesn't need `synchronized`, he's using `Locks`. He's just using them wrong.

Comment: @Kayaman Actually, he doesn't need any locks in Action class. The whole design isn't good what I'm saying and proposed better and simpler design

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun I know what you're saying, but you're proposing (hopefully) a `synchronized/wait()/notify()` solution instead of a more modern `lock/await()/signal()`.

Comment: Per the assignment i can not use the synchronize block

Comment: @Kayaman No. I'm proposing don't do external synch at all. I'm proposing doing internal synch. In this case you don't need and wait/notify in your client code.

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun His question even states: "it should run until the balance is two low and **wait** for a deposit thread.". So yes, he's going to need wait/notify functionality. You're right that it's not smart design to have the locking in an `Action` class, but you're wrong about his actual problem.

Comment: @Johnathan I see. So remove 'synchrinized' from my example and put your 'accessLock' instance inside Bank class. With this you'll have guided bank instance and no external synch.